# Can't login with google on ios app

Tags: support, login, ios-app

I've been using the IOS StackExchange app for a couple of years now, without a problem. Today I got a new iPhone Xs, downloaded the app, and tried to log in using Google, the way I always do. Each time I tried, I got the error message shown below, so I'm doing what it says. All of my other Google logins on the same phone have worked fine, and my StackExchange/Google login works fine on my desktop. Is there some strange interaction among StackExchange, IOS, and Google that I'm not understanding?

[image]

Comment: A bug report on Meta Stack Exchange: [Can't login with Google on iPhone XR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317598). And on Meta StackOverfflow: [Unable to log in with Google account to the Stack Overflow iOS app (Request failed)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372621).

Comment: And meta.MO: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3965/i-can-t-log-in-the-ios-app